# Reading comma separated values in python until new blank line character

Tags: python

I want to read input from STDIN like this:

```
1,0
0,0
1,0
1,0
```

and so on until the new line is empty(\n). This signifies the end of the input.

I did this

```
while (raw_input()!='\n'):
    actual,predicted=raw_input().split(',')
```

Gave me this error when I entered "enter" in last input

```
0,0
0,1
1,0
1,1
1,1

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-3ec5186ad531> in <module>()
      5 
      6 while (raw_input()!='\n'):
----> 7     actual,predicted=raw_input().split(',')
      8     if (actual==1 and predicted==1):
      9         t_p+=50

ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Don't ask a series of questions like this. Ask a new question.

Comment: It's the same code so asked here. Otherwise new question would require putting new information

Comment: @JonathonReinhart is right that you should ask a new question. It's not the same code, and if people answer your new question here the answers won't have anything to do with the title of this one. Plus you should give credit to TomMcDermott for helping you without requiring him to continue beyond solving the original problem.  In any case, your new problem is that split is giving you strings which you are then comparing to integers. Either convert to ints before comparing, or compare to "1" and "0".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, there are two problems here: [raw_input](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=raw_input#raw_input) strips the trailing newline, so a blank input becomes an empty string, not a newline.

The larger issue is that raw_input consumes the input, so your code won't work properly - it will only process every second line. The while loop calls raw_input (which uses up some input and discards it), then the body of the loop calls it again and assigns it to actual and predicted.

The python idiom for this task is a `while True:` loop containing a `break`:

```
while True:
    line = raw_input()
    if not line:
        break
    actual, predicted = line.split(",")
    print("a, p", actual, predicted)
print("done!")
```

Comment: Hi @Tom. This is good and worked. But I have got another small error. Pls check edit.

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input()` strips the trailing newline, so you want to compare to `''`.

But you're also reading two lines at a time in your loop, where I think you want something more like:

```
data = raw_input()
while (data != ''):
    actual,predicted=data.split(',')
    data = raw_input()
```

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input` is really used when you're writing a user-interactive program. It sounds like your program is a more typical UNIX program which processes file input.

`sys.stdin` is an open file. Because of this, you can use my favorite feature of Python which is iterating over each line in a file.  Ditch the `raw_input` altogether and just treat your data as if it were a file:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    parts = line.split(',')
```

Comment: No i am taking input from user. StDIN

Comment: Standard input is very commonly also used when piping the output of one program to the input of another. E.g. `cat /etc/passwd | grep root`